# Automated email sent using Bash mail function gets filtered as spam by Gmail

Tags: email, spam

I have a Bash script which is scheduled to run everyday and sends out user notification emails using a command like:

mail -s "Hello World" someone@gmail.com

Why is this email detected as spam by Gmail. Is there something I can do so that Gmail doesn't spam the email?

Answer (score 1):

It might be because Gmail is super strict about their mail policies. You should add a SPF record, something like

```
v=spf1 ip4:ipofdomain include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Also Gmail works with [dkim](http://www.dkim.org/)

You should set this up. And also check if your [blacklisted](http://multirbl.valli.org/)